# MySQL creating and populating the database

Tags: sql, mysql

I have downloaded the MySQL 5.2.5.1 version. I need to create the database and populate it. O have the data file in .csv format. I'm running the Mysql on windows. So when I create the database and a table in it, I want to populate the data from a file on my PC which is in .csv format.
I did it in this way:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
```

But it is not working for me. Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Define "is not working". Please *always* add all relevant error messages, and additional info like your table structure, and the structure of your CSV file. Otherwise, nobody can answer your question.

Comment: Also, for a quicker start, consider using a graphical frontend like http://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: When I load the data and checking it if it being populated or not, then it is not showing up the added data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change

```
lines terminated by '\n'
```

to

```
lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Comment: Then how do i check if the data has been populated into the table?what should be the command?